# I am trying to merge 2 lists into a single list and it's having TypeError while using the zip and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am trying to merge 2 lists into `newList` like below.

```
temp=[2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 

counT=['h', 'i', ' ', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'u']

newList = [(2,'h'),(1,'i'),.........(1,'u')]
```

This is the error i get:

> 'list' object is not callable

```
s="Hi how are you"
s = s.lower()
temp =[]
counT=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    counter = s.count(s[i])
    if s[i] not in temp:
        temp.append(s[i])
        counT.append(counter)

newList = zip(temp,counT)
newList = list(newList)
print(newList)
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/XjtTbT)

Comment: @Ravi Please post the entire traceback; which line raises the Error?

Comment: The second last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the below:

```
print(list(zip(temp, counT)))
```

You're over-complicating the task, just need to use above, don't need use the loop.

Comment: This doesn't answer the op's question of "what I am doing wrong?"

Comment: I'm not over-complicating the task I have used the loop to append the frequency of each word and store them in 2 list, one will contain the characters and one will contain the frequency ,and the main thing was to merge them into a single list like I have shown but I am getting error by using print(list(zip(temp, counT))) IDK why...

Comment: @Ravi i know why, you must have declared a variable named `list` in the code, change it then it must work

Answer (score 1):

Other people said where the error was coming from, but personally I would like to reply also to help with the style of the code.

```
s = "Hi how are you"
s = s.lower()
letters = []
counters = []
for char in sentence:
    if char not in letters:
        letters.append(char)
        counters.append(s.count(char))

new_list = list(zip(counters, letters))
print(new_list)
```

I think it's much more explicit than using `temp` variables and looping through the `range(len(...))` instead of looping on the elements themselves (`character` instead of `s[i]`).